# Count the number of occurrences of each character, i.e., how many times each letter, number, and punctuation character is used

Tags: intersystems-cache, mumps

I am trying to write a routine that counts the characters in a global.

These are the globals I set and the characters I would like counted.

```
 s ^XA(1)="SYLVESTER STALLONE, BRUCE WILLIS, AND ARNOLD SCHWARZENEGGER WERE DISCUSSING THEIR "
 s ^XA(2)="NEXT PROJECT, A BUDDY FILM IN WHICH BAROQUE COMPOSERS TEAM UP TO BATTLE BOX-OFFICE IRRELEVANCE "
 s ^XA(3)="EVERY HAD BEEN SETTLED EXCEPT THE CASTING. "
 s ^XA(4)="""ARNOLD CAN BE PACHELBEL,"" STALLONE. ""AND I WANT TO PLAY MOZART. """
 s ^XA(5)="""NO WAY!"" SAID WILLIS. ""YOU'RE NOT REMOTELY MOZARTISH. """ 
 s ^XA(6)="""I'LL PLAY MOZART. YOU CAN BE HANDEL. """
 s ^XA(7)="""YOU BE HANDEL!"" YELLED STALONE. ""I'M PLAYING MOZART! """
 s ^XA(8)="FINALLY, ARNOLD SPOKE ""YOU WILL PLAY HANDEL,"" HE SAID TO WILLIS. "
 s ^XA(9)="""AND YOU,"" HE SAID TO STALLONE, ""THEN WHO ARE YOU GONNA PLAY? """
 s ^XA(10)="""OH YEAH?"" SAID STALLONE, ""THEN WHO ARE YOU GONNA PLAY? """
 s ^XA(11)="ARNOLD ROSE FROM THE TABLE AND DONNED A PAIR OF SUNGLASSES. "
 s ^XA(12)="I'LL BE MOZART."
```

Comment: Presume the tag `m` is referring to `MUMPS` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS) and not Power Query Formula language.

Comment: Yes I am referring to MUMPS apologies.

Comment: Here's a hint, what does $L(^XA(1),$E(^XA(1),1)) do?

Comment: I entered $L(^XA(1),$E(^XA(1),1)) and received a value of 9. I believe it gave me the total S's. However, I only counted 8 S's. Where is the additional value coming from?

^XA(1)="SYLVESTER STALLONE, BRUCE WILLIS, AND ARNOLD SCHWARZENEGGER WERE DISCUSSING THEIR "

Comment: It doesn't give the count of S's. it technically gives you the number of substrings created by dividing up the string with S's. Which is the number of s's +1. I actually like ZitRo's way of doing it better in this instance though. Note with minor changes, you can make his code work in GT.M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, and you just need the total count of all characters in a global, here you go:

```
    set key = ""
    for {
        set key = $Order(^XA(key))
        quit:key=""
        for i=1:1:$Length(^XA(key)) {
            set char = $Extract(^XA(key), i)
            set count(char) = $get(count(char)) + 1
        }
    }
    zwrite count // or just return count
```

As for your example, this will produce the following output:

```
count(" ")=112
count("!")=3
count("""")=24
count("'")=4
count(",")=9
count("-")=1
count(".")=11
count("?")=3
count("A")=54
count("B")=12
count("C")=13
count("D")=23
count("E")=60
count("F")=6
count("G")=8
count("H")=20
count("I")=28
count("J")=1
count("K")=1
count("L")=48
count("M")=11
count("N")=39
count("O")=44
count("P")=13
count("Q")=1
count("R")=28
count("S")=29
count("T")=33
count("U")=13
count("V")=3
count("W")=11
count("X")=3
count("Y")=21
count("Z")=6
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: to count as real mumps, you'll have to use the short forms of the commands though

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps out tremendously.

Comment: @kazamatzuri, I would always prefer readability over concise and short code, however, I understand that it is very common for MUMPS to shorten everything. As noted in [this perfect presentation](https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/source/MUMPS-MDH/MumpsTutorial.pdf), "The legacy of small memory machines can still be seen to this day, as Mumps
programmers tend to abbreviate their code, sometimes excessively, although the original reason for doing so is long past.".

Comment: @BenjaminFuentes, you're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted here if it works for you :) Thanks!